# Find $\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4}$ where $\alpha > 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How can we find the following limit? $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4}\qquad \alpha>0$$

By using the polar coordinate, we get
$$\lim_{r\to 0}r^{\alpha+2}\frac{\cos^\alpha\theta \sin^4\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4{\theta}}=0$$ if $\theta\notin\{\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k:k\in\Bbb Z\}$.
Now, if $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$, then we get $$\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4}=0.$$
Can we conclude that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4}=0?$$

Comment: This only proves that the limit is $0$ if $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along a ray through the origin, because you aren't allowing $\theta$ to vary.

Comment: The careful way to proceed is to take $x^2 + y^4 = C$ as a constraint, then use Lagrange multipliers to find the constrained maximum of $x^\alpha y^4.$ In this case the calculations are not bad. Note we may take $x > 0,$ the original function ought to have been $|x|^\alpha y^4...$

Comment: $y^4/(x^2+y^4)\le 1$

Comment: also true...........

Comment: @WillJagy For values of $a=\frac{p}{2q+1}$ for any integers $p$ and $q$, the restriction $x\ge0$ is not required.  Moreover, if we permit $a>0$ such that $x^a\in \mathbb{C}$ when $x<0$, we can still show that the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that since $\alpha > 0$ and $x^2 \geq 0$ you have that
$$ \frac{x^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4} \leq \frac{x^\alpha y^4}{y^4} = x^\alpha \overset{(x,y) \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0.$$
Thus it is clear that one has $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4} = 0$. You rarely need polar coordinates for these kinds of questions. The most problems I encountered personally are easy to solve by using this trick above. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: I don't see how you use this technique to handle something general like $x^\alpha y^\beta/(x^2+y^4)$ when $\alpha<2$ and $\beta<4$.

Comment: @TedShifrin You got a good point there. But honestly most exercises of this type that I encountered are of the case $\alpha > 2$ or $\beta > 4$ (these typically come up in the first year at university). Of course for the case you mentioned one has to be more clever in one's approach.

Comment: @Yaddle From the AM-GM inequality we have $$\left|\frac{x^ay^b}{x^2+y^4}\right|\le \frac12 |x|^{a-1}|y|^{b-2}$$And equality holds when $x=\pm y^2$

Comment: Indeed that is a nice observation.

Answer (score 1):

From the AM-GM inequality we have $$\left|\frac{x^ay^b}{x^2+y^4}\right|\le \frac12 |x|^{a-1}|y|^{b-2}$$

where we assume that either $a$ is such that $x^a\in \mathbb{R}$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $0$ or that the limit is taken as $(x,y)\to (0^+,0)$.

And equality holds when $x=\pm y^2$.  Hence, we find

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^ay^b}{x^2+y^4}=0$$

whenever we have $2a+b>4$. The limit fails to exist otherwise.

In the case at hand, $a=\alpha$ and $b=4$ and we see that the limit is $0$ for $\alpha>0$ and fails to exist otherwise.

Comment: Although your argument isn't necesarry to solve the question I really like how you extended my argument to more general settings by using the AM-GM inequality. Espiecally you achieved a "sharp bound" on the exponents which is a good result for this trick. I really like it :)

Comment: @Yaddle Thank you and pleased this was useful.  Your answer is fine, but it does not show that the limit fails to exist for $\alpha\le 0$.